# PHP - How to Post Form Data to a URL, Wait for a Response & Then Do Something

Tags: php, post, curl, get

I'm going to give a basic example of what I need to be able to do, in the hopes that somebody can point me in the right direction, although I'm sure what I'm asking somebody is going to facepalm themselves when they read it.  Anyway, here goes.

I have a form on a page on Site Y (let's call it form.php), that form looks like this (asks for just a username & password):

```
<form action="http://SiteX.com/validate.php" method="post">
Email Address: <input type="text" name="email">
Password: <input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

As you can see, the form is hosted on Site Y, and is submitting the information to a page on Site X.

validate.php on Site X checks the submitted login details from Site Y and returns whether or not the login details are valid, sort of like this (obviously something more complex than this):

```
$SubmittedEmail = $_POST['email'];
$SubmittedPassword = $_POST['password'];

$CrossReferenceEmail = 'someemail@dontcare.com';
$CrossReferencePassword = 'apassword';

if ( ($SubmittedEmail == $CrossReferenceEmail) && ($SubmittedPassword == $CrossReferencePassword) ) {
echo 'Valid';
} else {
echo 'Not Valid'; }
```

What I need to do, that I don't know how to do, is how do I make "form.php" wait for a reply (whether the login details are valid or not) and then do something based on that reply?

Comment: you can post your login data to the site X via Jquery POST method while you being in site Y..And you need to get the respond back to site Y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form id="Form" action="http://SiteX.com/validate.php" method="post">
Email Address: <input type="text" name="email">
Password: <input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit">
</form>


$("#Form").submit(function(event) {

  /* stop form from submitting normally */
  event.preventDefault();

  /* get some values from elements on the page: */
  var $form = $( this ),
      e = $form.find( 'input[name="email"]' ).val(),
      p = $form.find( 'input[name="password"]' ).val(),
      url = $form.attr( 'action' );

  /* Send the data using post */
  var posting = $.post( url, { email: e,password:p } );

  /* Put the results in a div */
  posting.done(function( data ) {
   if(data=='valid')
   alert('login successful');
   elseif(data=='Not Valid')
   alert('login not successful');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

very basic and simple way is using **httpRequest** by **java script** and get returned value from site X and if match submit data to any php file in site Y. if you like to know I can send an example to help you.

this way is more user friendly but need client side process.
other way is use get content function.

**other way:**

you can use **get.php** file on site Y and submit data to **get.php** .

in **get.php** file use the **file_get_content** function and submit username data by get method ( add to the end of url like example )
then check the returned value ( true or false )

example :

```
$SubmittedEmail = $_POST['email'];
$SubmittedPassword = $_POST['password'];

$homepage = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/x.php?email=SubmittedEmail &password=$SubmittedPassword&...[other parameters]");
```

on www.x.com/x.php

you can get email and password by get method
and echo the result.

returnet value in **$hompage** is the result of x.php file on site x (true or false or any thing you echo on site x file x.php)

on site x.com/x.php do like this to get data and return result to y site:

```
 $SubmittedEmail = $_GET['email'];
 $SubmittedPassword = $_GET['password'];
if ( ($SubmittedEmail == $CrossReferenceEmail) && ($SubmittedPassword == $CrossReferencePassword) ) {
echo 'true';
} else {
echo 'false'; }
```

more help on:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

this way... you CAN'T as soon as the form is transmitted, the url will be set to "validate.php" so the original form.php and it's code is not available anymore.

What you could do is change the formtransmission to a ajax-javascript, that'll wait for the response from validate.php without closing form.php... you could then do whatever you need to do with it.

(what's that got to do with curl?)

[edit]

Add this javascript to the form.php html output

```
function validate()
{
    var e = $('email').value;
    var p = $('password').value; //jQuery is easier to type
    // the same as
    // var p = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var req = new Request({
        url: '/validate.php?',
        method: 'post',
        data: {'email' : e, 'password' : p},
        onComplete: function(response)
        {
            if (response == "Valid" ) 
            {
                //do what you want on success
            }
            else
            {
                // do what you want on unsuccessful login
            }
        }
    }).send();
}
```

now edit the form (just the first line)

```
<form onsubmit="validate();" method="post">
```

that should do